# Communication between pods and services in GCP between different clusters linked in VPC network

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, vpc

I have 2 clusters in GCP, one in Europe and the other in USA.
I have created a VPC network to peer the subnetworks each others and configured the relative firewall rules.
Now i'm able to create calls between pods, but i obtain a timeout when try to create them from a pod in europe to a service in the other cluster. I checked very well all firewall rules but can't find a solution. Can someone give me some hint to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that GCP requires to use a VM IP address in order to communicate outside the VPC. For allowing cross cluster communication on top of VPN, you need to make sure the clusters can communicate as they are on the same virtual network. GKE blocks egress traffic in case an internal IP address (pod address space) is used to access the internal IP address which are outside the virtual network (in this case through VPN). Hence you need to configure an ip table rule to masquerade traffic as it was originated from the VM instance IP address instead of the pod IP address for all outgoing traffic to the other subnet.

There is an implementation that is using daemon set to define the iptables MASQUERADE rules.

You can find more details on the github page - https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/ip-masq-agent and on the k8s documentation - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/ip-masq-agent/

Comment: Thank you. I want to describe better my situation: I have a RabbitMQ cluster in USA with a ClusterIP type service and a pod with ubuntu in Europe. From the ubuntu pod i can create a TCP connection to a RabbitMQ pod in USA, but I can't when i try to create the same connection to the RabbitMQ cluster service. 
I checked firewall rules logs: in Europe my egress rule accept both destination, but in USA in ingress rule i can see log only with destination pod IP, no log to service IP

Comment: @maurotinto did you try to create a loadbalancer with internal ip and to try to use it for the communication instead of a ClusterIP service. To do that add an annotation cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal" to the service and change the type of the service to LoadBalancer. To get a static IP you can set the IP address as well